# How to create a class for an object with two parents on PHP?

Tags: php, inheritance, model-view-controller

I have the following question. For an assignment I was given a data model for a PHP project using OOP which I have only done with more simple examples in  the past.

The thing is that I have one object or table that's called Recipes and there's another one called Detail_recipe which depends on Recipes however this table has another FK from Medicine.

So I thought that it must be required to use double inheritance which I know is frowned upon but I don't know what else to do. Plus I've thought about changing the model moving Detail_recipe to Recipes but I can't modify it.

What can I do?

Comment: What you want is multiple inheritance, where you implement two interfaces. I don't think that's frowned upon at all. It all depends on the situation.

Comment: I guess table implies database and therefore FK stands for foreign key. So the specific question is about object-relational mapping? Is it purely abstract or do you use an exisiting system (which not to say limits but directs you)?

Comment: Yeah, it's supposed to be a website made in PHP and using MySQL as the database.

Comment: Welcome to the world of Traits. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: Wait this sounds like single inheritance. Why do you need double?

Comment: I need to instance classes and as I understand traits bring methods but can't be instantiated.

Comment: Foreign key doesn't imply inheritance. I can have a Bicycles table with a column "owner" with an FK referencing "people" but that doesn't make a bicycle a person. The only inheritance I see is from Recipe.

Comment: Why dont you use composition instead